# Create dynamic options menu with kdialog   bash script : Printf can't do the job ? quoting issue 

Tags: bash, printf, quoting

i would like create a menu with kdialog like this

```
  kdialog --menu "choose your profile"  "\"-vcodec mpeg2\"" "mpeg" 
  "\"vcodec stuff -ab 100ak\"" "avi" "\"-acodec mp3 -ab 128k"\" "mp3"
```

now

array a contains options
array b contains name of a profile

it seems kdialog has some problem with "-ab"  generally it seemes it takes -stuff like an option so it needs to be "\"-vcodec mpeg2\"".

basically my problem is a quoting problem , i have used printf but i can't get it

this is my code:

> a=(-vcodec mp3 -ab 128k, -vcodec mpeg2video -b 1200k -ab 128k -acodec mp3 -r 25 -ar 44100 ) ; b=(mp3, mpg) ; eval kdialog --menu "choose your profile" $(for ((i = 0; i <=$(( ${#a[@]} -1 )) ; i++ )) ; do printf "\\'%s\\'  %s  "  "${a[i]}" "${b[i]}"  ; done)

solution

file to read $HOME/FFmpeg_profiles.lst

```
mpeg  -vcodec mpeg2 -ab 1000k 
avi  -vcodec avi -ab 1000k   
mp3 -acodec mp3 -ab 128k
```

script i did

```
function_load_profiles(){
k=0
while read line; do 

nameprofile[$k]="$(echo "$line" | awk '{print $1}')"
ffmpegoptionprofile[$k]="$(echo "$line" | awk '{ for(b=2; b<=NF; b++) {printf("%s ", $b)} } ' )"


 k=$(( $k+1 ))
done < "$HOME/FFmpeg_profiles.lst"

}

function_load_profiles 

ARGS="--menu \"choose your profile\" --"
for ((i=0; i<${#nameprofile[@]}; i++)); do
    ARGS="$ARGS \"${ffmpegoptionprofile[$i]}\" \"${nameprofile[$i]}\""
done

SELECTED_OPTIONS=$(echo $ARGS | xargs kdialog)
echo $SELECTED_OPTIONS
```

Comment: +1 Good question, nicely formatted, shows considerable evidence of researching and struggling with your problem! Welcome to S.O. Please remember to accept the answer that better solves your problem, if any, by pressing the checkmark sign , http://i.imgur.com/uqJeW.png.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
A=("-vcodec mp3 -ab 128k"  
   "-vcodec mpeg2video -b 1200k -ab 128k -acodec mp3 -r 25 -ar 44100")
B=("mp3" "mpg")

# Build command line args
ARGS="--menu \"choose your profile\" --"
for ((i=0; i<${#A[@]}; i++)); do
    ARGS="$ARGS \"${A[$i]}\" \"${B[$i]}\""
done

SELECTED_OPTIONS=$(echo $ARGS | xargs kdialog)
echo $SELECTED_OPTIONS
```

We use `xargs` to overcome the issue of the quoted options (with spaces) being treated as multiple args instead of a single argument, i.e. "`kdialog $ARGS`" won't work as expected.

`xargs` is preferable to "`eval kdialog $ARGS`" as it can avoid *command injection*.

---

#### Updates

Based on your updated example where you're actually loading the values form a text file, you can do the same without the intermediate arrays:

```
#!/bin/bash
PROFILE_FILE="FFmpeg_profiles.lst"
ARGS="--menu \"choose your profile\" --"

while read PROFILE OPTS; do
    ARGS="${ARGS} \"${OPTS}\" \"${PROFILE}\""
done < $PROFILE_FILE

echo $ARGS | xargs kdialog
```

Comment: function_load_profiles(){
k=0
while read line; do 
nameprofile[$k]="$(echo "$line" | awk '{print $1}')"
ffmpegoptionprofile[$k]="$(echo "$line" | awk '{ for(b=2; b<=NF; b++) {printf("%s ", $b)} } ' )"
 k=$(( $k+1 ))
done < "$HOME/FFmpeg_profiles.lst"
}
function_load_profiles 

ARGS="--menu \"choose your profile\" --"
for ((i=0; i<${#nameprofile[@]}; i++)); do
    ARGS="$ARGS \"${ffmpegoptionprofile[$i]}\" \"${nameprofile[$i]}\""
done

SELECTED_OPTIONS=$(echo $ARGS | xargs kdialog)
echo $SELECTED_OPTIONS`

Comment: @user1088530 added another example to match solution you added to your question.

Answer (score 1):

put a -- to indicate end of option processing, like this:

```
kdialog --menu "choose your profile" -- "-vcodec mpeg2" "mpeg" "vcodec stuff -ab 100ak" "avi" "-acodec mp3 -ab 128k" "mp3"
```

Regards

Comment: a=(-vcodec mp3 -ab 128k, -vcodec mpeg2video -b 1200k -ab 128k -acodec mp3 -r 25 -ar 44100 ) ; b=(mp3, mpg) ; kdialog --menu "choose your profile" --  $(for ((i = 0; i <=$(( ${#a[@]} -1 )) ; <i++ )) ; do printf "\"%s\" %s " "${a[i]}" "${b[i]}" ; done)
look at this http://wstaw.org/m/2011/12/09/plasma-desktopqC1493.jpg ok but there is still a wrong ouput

Comment: I see, my reply answers only the first part of you question, "how to prevent kdialog from interpreting arguemts that start with a dash as options?".

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
a=("-vcodec mpeg2" "mpeg" "vcodec stuff -ab 100ak" "avi" "-acodec mp3 -ab 128k" "mp3")
kdialog --menu "Choose your profile:" $(printf ' "%s" %s' "${a[@]}")
```

This uses just one array `a`, if you have two (`a` and `b`) just merge them into a third, like so:

```
a=(a b c) b=(1 2 3) j=0
for i in ${!a[@]}; do c[j++]="${a[i]}"; c[j++]="${b[i]}" ;done
echo "${c[1]}"
1
```

EDIT:

Original question has been modified, here's a new solution that might work:

```
options=$(sed -e '1i\echo kdialog --menu "Choose your profile:"'\
              -e 's/\s*\(\w*\)\s*\(.*\S\)\s*/"\2" \1/' $HOME/FFmpeg_profile.lst |\
        paste -sd' ' | sh)
```

1. Build the `kdialog` command from the `FFmpeg_profile.lst` file.
2. Each option and menu tag are on separate lines, so use `paste` to pivot them.
3. Pipe the `kdialog` command through the shell and save the interpolated result in a variable.